# Update a DB using data retrived from a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I Have a table named FRANCE like this

```
  City          Region            LAT   LNG
  PARIS         L'Ile-de-France  
  MARSEILLE     Provenza
```

Now, LAT and LNG values I retrieve throught a function that use google api. To do this I must concatenate City and Region

So this is what I do:

```
$sql="Select * from France";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$city=$row['city'];
$region=$row['region'];

 $address=$city.",".$region.", France";

$coordinates = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' .      urlencode($address) . '&sensor=true');
$coordinates = json_decode($coordinates);

$lat = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
 }
```

Now I'd like to update the table FRANCE to have this output

```
  City          Region            LAT         LNG
  PARIS         L'Ile-de-France   48.856614   2.352222
  MARSEILLE     Provenza          43.296482   5.369780
```

How can I do?

Comment: after gathering the results, then just create an update statement, then after thats processed, then make another select. and try to use mysqli or PDO with prepared statements instead.

Comment: thanks ghost could you show me an example please?sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straightforward, just like the comments above, you already got the fetching of results and made the request. After gathering the response from the request just make that `UPDATE` statement.

Obligatory note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Here is a rough untested example using mysqli with prepared statements. Of course you need to modify those items:

```
// first step connect and make the first query
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM france';
$query = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    // fetch and assign results
    $id = $row['id'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $region = $row['region'];
    $address = $city.",".$region.", France";

    // make the google request and gather results
    $coordinates = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&sensor=true');
    $coordinates = json_decode($coordinates);

    // check if there are results
    if($coordinates != null) {
        $lat = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lng = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        // make the update
        $sql2 = 'UPDATE france SET `LAT` = ?, `LNG` = ? WHERE id = ?';
        $update = $db->prepare($sql2);
        // i don't know if this is double column or varchar
        $update->bind_param('ddi', $lat, $lng, $id);
        $update->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: fatantastic...thanks so much...I don't know the part You call //make update..thanks a lot!

Comment: @cicciopasticcio basically that code block makes the update on that  row. glad this helped